# Extreme Overfitting CNN for MNIST

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, mnist

Im coding a simple CNN for classify mnist digits, something fairly simple, but the model is overfitting very fast, by a wide margin

i implement counter_overfitting techniqques like dropout, batch norm, data augmentation but the model simple never improves

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random
from PIL import Image

class ConvBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Convolutional Block featuring Conv2D + Pooling"""

    def __init__(self, conv_deep=1, kernels=32, kernel_size=3, pool_size=2, dropout_rate=0.4):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__(self)

        self.conv_layers = []
        self.pooling_layers = []
        self.bnorm_layers = []
        self.dropout_layers = []
        for index in range(0, conv_deep):
            self.conv_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=kernels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding="same", activation="relu"))
            self.pooling_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool_size))
            self.bnorm_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
            self.dropout_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        output = inputs

        for (conv, pooling, bnorm, dropout) in zip(self.conv_layers, self.pooling_layers, self.bnorm_layers, self.dropout_layers):
            output = conv(output)
            output = pooling(output)
            output = bnorm(output)

            if training:
                output = dropout(output)

        return output

class DigitsClassifier(tf.keras.Model):
    """MNIST Digit Classifier"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(DigitsClassifier, self).__init__(self)

        self.conv_input = ConvBlock(conv_deep=2, kernels=32)
        self.conv_hiden = ConvBlock(conv_deep=1, kernels=16)

        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.hiden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, "relu")
        self.bnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.softmax = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, "softmax")

    def call(self, inputs):

        output = self.conv_input(inputs)
        output = self.conv_hiden(output)

        output = self.flatten(output)
        output = self.hiden(output)
        output = self.bnorm(output)
        output = self.softmax(output)

        return output

#Load Train Data
(train_digits, train_labels), (eval_digits, eval_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data("./Resources")
kaggle_digits = pd.read_csv("./Resources/test.csv").values

#Preprocess
train_digits = np.reshape(train_digits, [np.shape(train_digits)[0], 28, 28, 1])/255.0
eval_digits = np.reshape(eval_digits, [np.shape(eval_digits)[0], 28, 28, 1])/255.0
kaggle_digits = np.reshape(kaggle_digits, [np.shape(kaggle_digits)[0], 28, 28, 1])/255.0

#Generator
def get_sample(digits, return_labels=False, labels=None):
    if(return_labels):
        if(np.shape(digits)[0] == np.shape(labels)[0]):
            for index in range(0, np.shape(digits)[0]):
                yield (digits[index], labels[index])
        else:
            raise ValueError("Digits and Labels dont have the same numberof samples")
    else:
        for index in range(0, np.shape(digits)[0]):
            yield (digits[index])

def transform_sample(digit, label):
    rot = random.randint(-1, 2)
    t_digit = digit
    t_digit = tf.compat.v2.image.rot90(t_digit, rot)

    return t_digit, label

#Define datasets
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_sample, (tf.float32, tf.int32), args=[train_digits, True, train_labels]).map(transform_sample, 100).batch(1000).prefetch(2)
eval_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_sample, (tf.float32, tf.int32), args=[eval_digits, True, eval_labels]).batch(1000).prefetch(2)
kaggle_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_sample, (tf.float32), args=[kaggle_digits]).batch(1000).prefetch(2)


for digits, label in train_ds.take(1):
    print(label)
    sns.regplot(data=digits)
    plt.show()


#Define model and load weights (Pretrained on google colab notebook)
model = DigitsClassifier()
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(7.0), tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=50, verbose=2, validation_data=eval_ds)
```

at this point i really dont know what to try, i will reduce model complexity but i dont think that will help

PD: counter-intuitive, stop using data augmentation techniques let the model improves, my data augmentation simple consist in a map function `transform_sample` that perform a random 90 degree rotation to every image, or not rotation at all

Comment: Hi @EiPapi, Tried reproducing your code but I got the error, "ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`." in the line, "model.fit". Also, can you please confirm what data is present in "Resources" Folder. I have replaced that line of code with below code:                                          
           (train_digits, train_labels), (eval_digits, eval_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Model is Overfitting, you can

1. `Shuffle` the Data, by using `shuffle=True` in `cnn_model.fit`. Code is shown below:

   `model.fit(train_ds, epochs=50, verbose=2, shuffle = True, validation_data=eval_ds)`
2. Use `Early Stopping`. Code is shown below

   `callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)`

   `model.fit(train_ds, epochs=50, verbose=2, callbacks=[callback], validation_data=eval_ds)`
3. Use `Regularization`. Code for `Regularization` is shown below (You can try `l1 Regularization` or `l1_l2 Regularization` as well). Code for the same is shown below.

`from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2`

`Regularizer = l2(0.001)`

`self.conv_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=kernels, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding="same", activation="relu", 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`

`self.hiden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, "relu",                activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`

`self.softmax = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, "softmax",                activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer)`

4. Finally, if there still no change, you can try using `Pre-Trained Models` like `ResNet` or `VGG Net`, etc..